# Decoding a JWT token from a .cer file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, jwt

I've been asked to solve a very specific problem.  An outside company will authorize the user, and create a JWT token for that user.  They will then send us a .cer file (.der and other file types are likely fine too).  I then have to decode the JWT within the file.

Our Rails app's current authorization system uses Devise

I've tried finding ways to do this in the JWT gem. I've tried using the OpenSSL library to somehow read the file and turn it into an object that `JWT.decode` will read.

Let me know if more info is needed

Comment: *decode the JWT within the file* - it's not really clear what this means. I could imagine that they send a public key as a .cer, so that you can validate the JWT with that key.

Comment: Yeah - this doesn't make any sense.  Going back to my boss and closing this ticket.  Thanks for the reply!